# NativeQuery with three single quotes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My query is failing due to three quotes. It could be another reason but from my knowledge it is caused by the three quotes. I can't seem to figure out a solution for this and I need additional help. I have tried escaping and everything else but can't seem to solve the issue.

I am using Spring Data JPA

```
@Query(value = "SELECT f FROM Fragrance f WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(f.name, ' &', ''), '' ', '') = ?1" , nativeQuery = true)
Fragrance findByNameIgnoreSpecialCharacters(String name);
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.findParameterRegistration(BaseQueryImpl.java:502) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unable to run the specified native query on any database so no wonder Hibernate finds it to be malformed.

> Specified query

```
SELECT
  f
FROM
  Fragrance f
WHERE
  REPLACE(REPLACE(f.name, ' &', ''), '' ', '') = ?1
```

---

There are two errors in this query. The first error is that `SELECT f FROM Fragrance f ...` requires there to be a column named `f` in the `Fragrance` table and presumably there is none. Remember, this is a native query not a JPA query. So, the correct query should begin with `SELECT * FROM Fragrance ...`.

The second error is that `'' '` is invalid text for a query. `''` means the single-quote character (`'`). So, this text does not start correctly. The correct text should be `''' '`.

> Correct query

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Fragrance
WHERE
  REPLACE(REPLACE(name, ' &', ''), ''' ', '') = ?1
```

[Sample working project](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/41642785) available on Github.